# Android smb jcifs alfresco

Tags: android, smb

I have two Android phones: smb server and client (jcifs library and alfresco is used). They are connected via wifi. when connection is failed, transmission stops and such error occures on client's side.

**

```
jcifs.d.a.d: Transport1 timedout waiting for response to SmbComReadAndX [command=SMB_COM_READ_ANDX,
received=false,
errorcode=0, flags=0x0018, flags2=0xC803, signSeq=0, tid=1, pid=6855, iud=0, mid=7529, wordcount=12,
bytecount=0, andxCommand=0xFF,
andxOffset=0, fid=0, offset=21340160, maxcount=8192, minCount=8192, openTimeout=-1, remaining=0, offset=21340160]
```

**

so, Is it possible to continue transmission after wifi network disconnection?

Maybe, it's possible to increase some meanings of timeouts? How can I do it on client's or server's side

And the last - after disconnection, client trys to connect to server with meaning of session = T2:

**`01-18 11:50:02.726: D/AndroidSMB(1967): [SMB] Connection from 192.168.1.241/192.168.1.241:54107, handler=[SMB,TCP-SMB,ALL:1445], sess=T2`**